# WSGI error: The application with bundle ID (null) is running setugid(), which is not allowed

Tags: macos, apache, mod-wsgi

I am trying to get to work the webplugin example in ete2 package in my own computer (Mac OS X Yosemite) (http://etetoolkit.org/docs/2.3/tutorial/tutorial_webplugin.html#module-ete2.webplugin)

I have reached to the point, where in apache2 error log I get the following errors:

```
[wsgi:error] [pid 1152] ['name'] The application with bundle ID (null) is running setugid(), which is not allowed.
[wsgi:error] [pid 1154] [client 127.0.0.1:51175] Truncated or oversized response headers received from daemon process 'webplugin_example': /Users/Liis/Sites/webplugin/wsgi/webplugin_example.py, referer: http://webplugin.com/
```

What I have done is:
1) I did everything said in http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2014/11/configure-apache-virtualhost-mac-os-x/
2) My /Sites folder consists of folder /webplugin 
As a result, the webplugin.com shows the main page, but if I click on the 'Draw tree' button, the little box with question mark shows up and the mentioned error messages appear to the log file.

3) My /Hosts/.conf file looks like this:

`LoadModule wsgi_module /usr/local/Cellar/mod_wsgi/4.4.11/libexec/mod_wsgi.so
WSGIPythonHome "/Users/Liis/anaconda"
WSGIPythonPath "/Users/Liis/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages"
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Users/Liis/Sites"
    WSGIDaemonProcess webplugin_example user=_www group=_www processes=1 threads=25 header-buffer-size=32768 python-path="/Users/Liis/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages"
    WSGIProcessGroup webplugin_example
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
    ServerName "webplugin.com"
    <Directory />
          Require all granted

          Options +FollowSymLinks

          AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    <Directory "/Users/Liis/Sites/webplugin/wsgi">
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        SetHandler wsgi-script
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        AddHandler wsgi-script .py
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>`

Any help would be good:)

I have a feeling that the error could be somehow related to the X server thing, but I have no idea how to fix that in Mac.

All the best,
L.